# curl 7.43.0 wont build with openssl 1.0.2d

Tags: curl, openssl, undefined

i try to build openssl and curl in my centos 6.6 x64,

first , build and install openssl is successful , and then try to build curl ,

but it is fail to build curl and show below error message ,

```
    ./lib/.libs/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_next_proto_select_cb'

    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

i have search a lot of pages but didnt find any related information ,

please help me to fixed this problem , thanks.

Comment: You didn't give enough information, so I'll suggest what I think could fix it. Make sure openssl-devel (openssl header files) is in the include path of the compiler and the openssl-libs (libssl.so) is in the linker path.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact issue. I commented out the following lines from **curl\lib\vtls\openssl.c**

```
if(data->set.ssl_enable_npn)
  SSL_CTX_set_next_proto_select_cb(connssl->ctx, select_next_proto_cb, conn);
```

and then build was successful. Not sure if it's a bug but somehow I managed to get a temporary fix.

The reason I feel it's a bug is because: SSL_CTX_set_next_proto_select_cb() is declared in **openssl\include\Ssl.h** but I cannot find its definition anywhere.